# Need only some columns to be sent in mail with one more column sorting criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got a code with updated, need a table with few columns and some more criteria for sorting date. First Need to sort column X with TAT>2, column B with banks, and only B,C,D,E,G,H,J,K,X columns need to be mailed. Kindly help me with it.

```
function createTable() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A2:AH");

  var criterias = ["Report Pending", "Site Visit Pending", "Query Raised"]
  var backgrounds = dataRange.getBackgrounds(); // Added
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Compliance Score</th><th>STSOR Value</th><th>STSOR %</th><th>ZZ lines</th><th>ZZ%</th><th>PI lines Counted</th><th>PI %</th><th>NRDS Value</th><th>NRDS %</tr></br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cells = data[i];
    if (cells[23] > 2 && criterias.indexOf(cells[9]) != -1) {
      table = table + "<tr>";
      for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
        table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]}">` + cells[u] + "</td>"; // Modified
      }
      table = table + "</tr>"
    }
  }

  //Send the email:
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "ramauni3994@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody: table
  });
}
```

Like this photo table need to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: If `Like this photo table need to be displayed.` is your expected output situation, can you provide your sample input situation for obtaining your expected output situation? And also, I cannot understand `sort column X with TAT>2, column B with banks`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function createTable() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A2:AH" + sheet1.getLastRow());
  dataRange.sort([{ column: 24, ascending: true }]);

  var criterias = ["Report Pending", "Site Visit Pending", "Query Raised"]
  var backgrounds = dataRange.getBackgrounds(); // Added
  var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1><tr><th>Compliance Score</th><th>STSOR Value</th><th>STSOR %</th><th>ZZ lines</th><th>ZZ%</th><th>PI lines Counted</th><th>PI %</th><th>NRDS Value</th><th>NRDS %</tr></br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cells = data[i];
    if (cells[23] > 2 && criterias.indexOf(cells[9]) != -1) {
      table = table + "<tr>";
      for (var u of [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 23]) { // B,C,D,E,G,H,J,K,X
        table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]}">` + cells[u] + "</td>"; // Modified
      }
      table = table + "</tr>"
    }
  }

  //Send the email:
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "###########@gmail.com",
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody: table
  });
}
```